# Clojure :post condition doesn't recognise %

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have a Clojure function with a post-condition :

```
{:post [(s/valid? ::MyQuery %)]}
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: % in this context, compiling:(polvo/core.clj:45:11)is.
```

It seems to not know what the % is.

But in every example I can find of Clojure :post that's what it uses to refer to the return value.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely explanation:  your pre/post map is not in the right position.

Comment: Yep. I actually had the :pre and :post in two different maps rather than the same one